# Same build.gradle file getting different versions for a dependency (org.json:json)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have imported a project which is running fine with my colleagues, however, a gradle dependency (**org.json:json**) is being imported as a different version although we are using the same build.gradle file shown below

My version of the dependency is 2013 & their version is 2010, where the `JSONObject.getString()` function is different in both causing errors in my machine when running the application.

How to ensure I get the same dependency like them & what caused this difference?

build.gradle file is shown below:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.ejada'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven  {
        url 'http://repo.enonic.com/public/'
    }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    compile files('libs/ojdbc6.jar')
    compile group: 'nl.captcha', name: 'simplecaptcha', version: '1.2.1'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.9'
    compile group: 'org.antlr', name: 'stringtemplate', version: '4.0.2'
    compile("org.json:json")

    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7')

    // For XML Response
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap")
    compile("com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")

    compile('org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile group: 'com.github.ulisesbocchio', name: 'jasypt-spring-boot-starter', version: '1.4-java7'
    compile('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api')
    compile("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")

}
```

Adding the output of the cmd  `gradlew dependencies --configuration runtime` as requested *(below is exactly the same from both machines)*:

```
runtime - Runtime dependencies for source set 'main' (deprecated, use 'runtimeOnly ' instead).
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: -> 1.5.9.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.9.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.9.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.5.9.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.11
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.11
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22 -> 1.7.25
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.25
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.5.9.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.23
|    |    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:8.5.23
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:8.5.23
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:8.5.23
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:8.5.23 (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.3.6.Final
|    |    +--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final -> 3.3.1.Final
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.1 -> 1.3.4
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.10
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.10
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.13.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-context-support: -> 4.3.13.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
+--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc: -> 4.3.13.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.13.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.13.RELEASE
+--- nl.captcha:simplecaptcha:1.2.1
+--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9
+--- org.antlr:stringtemplate:4.0.2
|    \--- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.3
|         \--- org.antlr:stringtemplate:3.2.1 -> 4.0.2 (*)
+--- org.json:json: -> 20140107
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml: -> 2.8.10
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.10
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.10 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.8.10
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.10
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.10 (*)
|    +--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4
|    \--- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:5.0.3
|         \--- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:3.1.4
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security: -> 1.5.9.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.9.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.3.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.3.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.3.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.3.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core: -> 2.3.2.RELEASE
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21 -> 1.7.25
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.4.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.4.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.4.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap: -> 4.2.3.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:2.2.0.RELEASE -> 2.3.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.3.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.3.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
+--- com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk: -> 3.2.1
+--- org.springframework:spring-tx: -> 4.3.13.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4
|    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools: -> 1.5.9.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.9.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.5.9.RELEASE (*)
+--- com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:1.4-java7
|    \--- com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:1.4-java7
|         \--- org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.2
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api: -> 3.1.0
+--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver: -> 1.8.13
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind: -> 2.8.10 (*)
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat: -> 1.5.9.RELEASE (*)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `gradle dependencies --configuration runtime` to figure out how different version is getting encluded. Later, you can exclude dependency from an unwanted group (or artifact) and define required version to dependency.

```
 compile('group:artifact:version') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json' 
 }
 compile("org.json:json:requiredVersion")
```

Comment: thanks, how to run that gradle cmd in eclipse? I can't find a terminal in it, or should i use an external terminal?
Also I think it is better to just indicate the required version without excluding, right?

Comment: I could run the cmd using a terminal in the project but with `gradlew` , but how the dependencies differed between the machines ?

Comment: yes, even that ('gradlew') will help. Can you please add output. that will help to figure out, from where it's getting different version  @AhmedElkoussy

Comment: updated the question as requested with the cmd output, surprisingly it is exactly the same in both machines @lucid

Comment: Can you give me some screenshot or something where I can check both versions. @AhmedElkoussy

Comment: I have compared them letter by letter in 2 different comparing tools & they were exactly the same shown, posting 2 exactly similar configurations like this will make the question too long without any benefit, the best way was to specify the version for the dependency to be the working one & not just depend on the default @lucid

Comment: what I meant was 'which other version you getting instead of 'org.json:json: -> 20140107'. just for sake of curiosity.

Comment: I am getting the same 'org.json:json: -> 20140107' in both, however the actual dependency retrieved in the machine that was working was 'org.json:json: -> 2009....'